# NSArrayController, NSPopupButton proper bindings

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I just started Mac programming coming over from iOS and was playing around with bindings.

I'm trying to make a simple directory popup that shows a history of recently selected directories and last element would read `other...` which will open the opendialog box.

I can't seem to figure out how to Bind an NSPopupButton to my Model though.

Its setup like this:
MainUIViewController, NSController, NSObject Controller all wired up in the nib

[image: the NIB file]

I do connect an outlet in MainUIViewController to the Directory Array Controller in the NIB
I have a class for eachDirectory, and a class for DirectoryArrayController(NSObject)  I bind the NSPopupButton on view this way:

[image: Directory Array Controller bindings]

and I have the Directory Array Controller bound to the Directory Popup Array Controller thus

[image: Directory Popup Array Controller bindings]

Here is the .h file that is connected to the Directory Popup Array Controller

```
@interface DirectoryPopupArrayController : NSObject
   @property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *directoryPopupButton;
   @property (nonatomic) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *allDirectoryHistory;
   @property (nonatomic) eachDirectory *currentlySelectedDirectory;
@end
```

I fill some sample directory info with the following code in the corresponding .m file

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //testing sample directories
    self.allDirectoryHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    NSString *name;
    eachDirectory *newDirectoryName;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"directory %d", i];
        newDirectoryName = [[eachDirectory alloc] initWithDirectoryName:name];

        [self.allDirectoryHistory addObject:newDirectoryName];
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the eachDirectory.h

```
@interface eachDirectory : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic) NSString *directoryPath;
  @property (nonatomic) NSString *directoryVisibleName;

  -(id) initWithDirectoryName:(NSString *)newName;
@end
```

Now When I go to my code if I place the code for creation of the Array and bind the Array controller directly to the UIViewController.m file things seem to work fine. 
 What I want to do is handle all the array stuff in a separate class file and only get back the final directory choice to the main controller.  When I bind the NSArrayController to the Object controller in the NIB as described above I get nothing showing in the popup and I don't understand why!

Any Help is greatly appreciated,  Sorry for the long-winded post - just wanted to make myself clear.